# MVC Route Configuration: Multiple route with different route name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-5

I have created multiple routes with different route name in MVC.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "PostDetails",
    url: "Ad/{id}/{item}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Post" }
);
```

I am calling route from a javascript function to redirect to this route

```
var url = '@Url.RouteUrl("PostDetails", new { id = "_id_", item = "_name_" })';     
url = url.replace("_id_", id).replace("_name_", name);
window.location.href = url;
```

This is giving an error with 404.

Comment: Is this script in the view or in an external `js` file?

Comment: What was the generated url in html?

Comment: @StephenMuecke this is like <br> function postDetails(id, name) {
        var url = '@Url.RouteUrl("PostDetails", new { id = "_id_", item = "_name_" })';
       
        url = url.replace("_id_", id).replace("_name_", name);
        window.location.href = url;
    }

Comment: That was not my question (nor have you responded to @ramiramilu comment.) Again, Is this in an external `js` file? (in which case it will not work). Add `console.log(url);` to your script and see what the output is.

Comment: oh.
@StephenMuecke its in a view

Comment: @ramiramilu the url i am getting  is 'ad/50567/test'

Comment: show us your `action` method code, and also we assume that this `route` is in top of your `routeconfig.cs`.

Comment: public ActionResult Post(string id)
        {
            if (Common.IsNumber(id))
            {
                ViewBag.ID = id;
                return View();
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }

        }

Comment: Your action should be - `public ActionResult Post(string id, string item) `. I added `string name` as one of the parameter to match your route. Try that way and let me know if it works.

Comment: added but still not working. http://localhost:5542/ad/50567/test 404

Comment: try to add namespaces: new[] { "YourApplicationName.Controllers" } to your MapRoute

Comment: does your `Post` action is in `Home` controller?

Comment: Yes it is in Home controller

Comment: Are there any other routes in the `routeconfig.cs` before this route?

Comment: Can you edit your question with Controller code ?

Comment: Yes i have multiple routes in routeconfig.cs

Comment: Please post your routes and controller code. This isn't a valid question unless it can be duplicated by others, and the code you have posted so far is clearly not the root cause of your issue. Put some effort into your question, and you will be more likely to get a useful answer.

Comment: Hi @NightOwl888 issue resolved it was not in sequence. Thanks.

Comment: @SatishSingh - Then you should mark the proposed solution as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You must add your route before Default route in the RouteConfig like:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "PostDetails",
            url: "Ad/{id}/{item}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Post" }
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
}
```